# Upload image to Google Cloud Storage (Java)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, cloud, google-cloud-storage

I want to develop a java-application (for pc) which can upload any picture to Google Cloud Storage. Although I have spent my whole evening on searching for a solution, I don't have any clue how to start. Does anyone of you have experience with uploading images to Google Cloud Storage? Are there better alternatives to Google Cloud Storage?

Comment: Have you looked at the google cloud SDK?

Comment: Yes, but I didn't get how i could write an java-app

Comment: Are you familiar with rest api's? You can use that to upload images. Google cloud supports that

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/googlecloudstorageclient/read-write-to-cloud-storage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can public your file, and then the media link of the blob can access anywhere.

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public

This is my solution.

```
try {
    FileInputStream serviceAccount =
            new FileInputStream("firebaseKey/serviceAccountKey.json");

    FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
            .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
            .setDatabaseUrl("https://xxxxx.firebaseio.com")
            .build();
    FirebaseApp fireApp = FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);

    StorageClient storageClient = StorageClient.getInstance(fireApp);
    InputStream testFile = new FileInputStream(file.getPath());
    String blobString = "NEW_FOLDER/" + "FILE_NAME.jpg";
    Blob blob = storageClient.bucket("xxxxxx.appspot.com")
                    .create(blobString, testFile , Bucket.BlobWriteOption.userProject("xxxxxxx"));
    blob.getStorage().createAcl(blob.getBlobId(), Acl.of(Acl.User.ofAllUsers(), Acl.Role.READER));
    System.out.println(blob.getMediaLink());
} catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 7):

There's a lovely Java API for using Google Cloud, including Storage:  http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-java/0.10.0/index.html

Here's an example desktop application that uses this library to upload and download files: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/blob/master/google-cloud-examples/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/examples/storage/StorageExample.java

Google Cloud Storage has quite a bit of documentation, guides, and tutorials. Here's the root of it all: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. In order to install the Java API, I have to install the google cloud sdk first, right?

Comment: Nope, unrelated. If you're using Maven or something, it's just one more dependency. It's a good idea to install the SDK anyway, though. You'll find the gcloud command is quite useful when working with Google Cloud.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

```
  @Override
  public String uploadImage(String fileName , String filePath,String fileType) throws IOException {
    Bucket bucket = getBucket("sample-bucket");
    InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(filePath));
    Blob blob = bucket.create(fileName, inputStream, fileType);
    log.info("Blob Link:"+blob.getMediaLink());
    return blob.getMediaLink();
  }


  private Bucket getBucket(String bucketName) throws IOException {
    GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream(CREDENTIALS_PATH))
        .createScoped(Lists.newArrayList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"));
    Storage storage = StorageOptions.newBuilder().setCredentials(credentials).build().getService();
    Bucket bucket = storage.get(bucketName);
    if (bucket == null) {
      throw new IOException("Bucket not found:"+bucketName);
    }
    return bucket;
  }
```

CREDENTIALS_PATH , Download when setting the service account , make sure the the user have the permission to upload the image in the bucket .